# Some doubts in expressjs related to image output

Tags: node.js, express

So here is my code

```js
 const response = await fetch(`http://example.com\?write=Hi+Pls+Help`); // when we go here shows a png image
    const headers = { "Content-Type": "image/png" };

  //set status code and headers
  res.writeHead(200, headers);
response.body.pipe(res);
```

And it just timesout if I stay on the web

I am trying to display another image from a backend server of mine that is fully dynamic

Please help me a way for it

Comment: Why escaped '?' in your query? This slash: `\?write=...`

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is whether the URL you are fetching from is correct and accessible from your backend server. You can try accessing the URL directly in your browser to see if the image loads properly.

Assuming the URL is correct, another thing to consider is the timeout setting for the HTTP request. By default, the timeout setting for a fetch request is usually set to "infinity", which means that it will wait indefinitely for a response. You can try setting a timeout value in your fetch options to prevent it from timing out, like this:

```js
const response = await fetch(`http://example.com\?write=Hi+Pls+Help`, { timeout: 5000 }); // set timeout to 5 seconds
```

This will set a timeout of 5 seconds for the fetch request. If the server does not respond within 5 seconds, it will throw a timeout error.

Lastly, you can also try logging any error messages that are thrown during the fetch request to get more information on why it is failing:

```js
try {
  const response = await fetch(`http://example.com\?write=Hi+Pls+Help`, { timeout: 5000 });
  const headers = { "Content-Type": "image/png" };
  res.writeHead(200, headers);
  response.body.pipe(res);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500).send('Error fetching image');
}
```

This will log any errors to the console and send a 500 error response to the client if the fetch request fails.

Comment: Doesnt work maybe there is some other method